# ActiveAdmin with Rails 3.1 breaking javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I just implemented the ActiveAdmin gem with my Rails 3.1 app, and it caused a problem with some javascript I have in my app which allows ajax posting of comments.  Removing the active_admin.js file causes the problem to go away.  How do I keep the active_admin's javascript while preserving the functionality of my app?  Any ideas on what the problems may be?

Contents of active_admin.js:

```
//= require active_admin/base
```

Contents of my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Javascript that is being broken by ActiveAdmin:

```
jQuery -> 
$('.addcomment').live("click", ->
 $(this).closest('.comment_area').find('.add_comment_box').parent().removeClass("add_comments_box_hidden").addClass('add_comments_box')
    return false )

init_csrf = ->
  window._settings.token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr 'content'
  $.ajaxSetup
    beforeSend: (xhr) ->
      xhr.setRequestHeader "X-CSRF-Token", _settings.token

jQuery ->
    $('.post_comment_btn').live("click", ->
        $(this).closest('.comment_area').addClass('add_comment_here')
        $.post(
            '/comments'
            $(this).closest('form').serialize()
            null
            "script"
        )
        return false )
```

Link to active_admin [github page](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this will help you ... I'm also using active_admin's javascript separately from the active_admin app. I faced a problem with double requests on clicking to "ajax links". The problem was caused by triggers in the vendor.js file. This has been fixed with the latest version of the gem (vendor.js has been removed) and proper inclusion statements in my application.js file.

I would suggest you to replace `//=require_tree .` with explicit require statements. Try one by one to add your deps till you find the problem.

Moreover, please provide us with the version of ActiveAdmin that you are using.

Comment: When I replace the '\\=require_tree .' with individual require statements for my js files, not including the active_admin.js file, it solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is ActiveAdmin includes its own version of jQuery, which overrides your version.  If you've added any plugins to jQuery, they will disappear.

Luckily there's an easy fix - don't explicitly include any javascript for ActiveAdmin.  You don't need to.  Active Admin knows to pull the javascript it needs from the ActiveAdmin gem.  So just delete that require line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete require line in active_admin.js, than delete or update link(default_actions) in index doesn't work, so let that line be and:

Replace `//= require_tree .` with exact js files in your assets one by one. This finally solved my problem !

Hope it'll save some time to someone. 
Regards